# Do any npm projects allows reading from a config file but overwriting with command line args?

Tags: npm, config, command-line-arguments

Working with node and need to read command line args or from a config file. I'm liking the idea of a library that handles both and reads from a config file and command line arguments. Command line arguments simply overwrite config file by default.

Do you know of any such npm library? Any suggestions or libraries that would work together nicely if I were to write such a library myself?

edit: Found exactly what I needed after a little bit more research. See answer below.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/source-configs

source-configs allows exactly this to be accomplished

Setup the config file and include command line params which overwrite the configured values.

Example:

```
// your-schema-js-file.json
{
  websocket: {
    host: {
      description: 'WebSocket host URL',
      default: 'localhost',
      commandLineArg: ['--websocket-host-url', '--ws-host', '-h'],
      envVar: ['WEBSOCKET_HOST_URL', 'WS_HOST']
    },
    port: {
      description: 'WebSocket port',
      default: 8081,
      commandLineArg: ['--ws-port', '-p'],
      envVar: 'WS_PORT'
    },
    protocol: {
      description: 'Which WebSocket protocol',
      values: ['ws', 'wss'],
      commandLineArg: '--ws-protocol',
      envVar: 'WS_PROTOCOL'
    },
    url: 'user defined function'
  }
}
```